# DDD Model Updates from Webservice

Tags: domain-driven-design

wi'm writing an online shop and while i was modelling the domain a question came to my mind, how to model objects that are changed from different systems with different granularity.

For e.g. let's say we have a Product entity with some Attributes:

- Produtnumber
- Name
- Description
- Price
- etc.

We receive new products and product updates from two systems: an inventory management system (via webservice) and a management web ui integrated in the e-commerce product.

From the inventory management i always get a full update of the product with all attributes (even if not all changed). The management ui updates single attributes (crud).

So how should i model (and name) the business case related change methods on the product entity?

Somethin like updateFromIms(price, description, name, ...) or should i write a setter for every attribute (which breaks the 'unmodifiable' entity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, I normally look at how the sample Shipping DDD application does it. The sample applicaiton in C# can be found: http://code.google.com/p/ndddsample/

So in your case, this is similar to how **Cargo** entity is treated, it has a constructor to create the entity, and then it has public methods like **SpecifyNewRoute** that is used by the **BookingService** to ChangeDestination or BookNewCargo. The BookingService is used by a **BookingFacade** that has the responsibility to:

> This facade shields the domain layer - model, services, repositories -
>   from concerns about such things as the user interface and remoting.

So in your case, your UI and WebService could call a single facade method called UpdateProduct (I don't think there is a conceptual difference between updating from a service or UI, so you don't need a separate method like ChangeDestination but it's your call). The facade methods will call into your **ProductService::UpdateProduct** method which will call into **ProductModel::UpdateProduct**

Now I don't know the scope of your application, so this could be too much but DDD is not for small applications anyhow. Personally, I take Eric Evans' book and NDD sample as a guidance but I don't see a problem with getting rid of some of the complexity (ignoring the facade for example), no one knows your application better than you.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know about the project you mentioned. I will have a closer look at it. But as far as i understand an update anything method is perferctly ok if it's an use case?

Comment: It's OK if they are conceptually similar. It doesn't add much to the richness of your model to have two separate methods in my opinion.